# Occasionally connected CQRS systems - Client and Server Commands - Task based screens

Tags: event-handling, command, user-experience, cqrs, event-sourcing

**Premise:**

It is recommended that in **CQRS+DDD+ES** style applications use **task** based screens, these screens guide the user and capture intent.

These **task** screens can also be referred to as **Inductive User Interface**.  Some examples of UI design guidelines that can help you create mondern, user-friendly apps:

**[Microsoft Inductive User Interface Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997506.aspx)** and,

**[Index of UX guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465424.aspx)**

The way I understand it, the **tasks**, generally speaking, should line up with **Commands** or **Functions** waiting on the Server.

For example, if the **User** makes a change to the **Customer's** [first name], generally speaking this should be an isolated **task** where a pop-up window or the like provides a mechanism for this event, and this event only.

[image]

**Questions:**

**Part-1:**

In the situation where the **User** is not just making a change to a **Customer's** [first name], but actually creating a new **Customer**.  Surely the **User** will not go from [first name] => to [last name] => to [address] => to [email], etc. -- in a wizard like style, where each wizard screen maps to a **Command**.

a) How are the screens laid out when it's just not practical to isolate a single task?  For example when creating a new **Customer** or **Inventory Item**.

[image]

b) What does the code and/or logic flow related to the **Commands** look like on the **Client** and **Server** in this situation, keeping in mind the obvious pull to stay consistent with the "normal" **task** based flow of the rest of the system?  After all, these all just translate to **Activities** or **Events** in the **Event Source**.

**Part-2:**

What if the **User** is not just making a change to a **Customer's** [first name], but their [last name], [address], and [phone number] -- all the while they **User** is off-line.

I think ultimately, the **User** should still be able to do real work on multiple tasks in different areas of the application, while off-line, and perform robust conflict resolution when coming back online.

a) What is the code and/or logic flow and/or artifacts related to the **Commands** on the **Client side** while the **User** is off-line while handling these events locally (IndexDb, queues, etc.)? and

b) What does the connection look like and how does it act when off-line (retries)?

c) What is the code and/or logic flow and/or artifacts related to the **Commands** on the **Client** and **Server side**, when the **User** comes back on-line?

d) What does the connection look like and how does it act when coming back on-line (reestablish of connection, if it is determined that the **Client** side **ViewModel** is stale, **WebSockets**, etc.)?

**Reference diagram:**

[image: Proposed CQRS architecture]

Comment: Just a heads up, I asked another question related to this one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222763/occasionally-connected-cqrs-system

Comment: Regarding, Part 1 a - when you create an item do you really have a *deactivation comment*?

Comment: In any event, I think you need to think about the business value of having a command specifically for first name change. Perhaps its enough to command the change of the customers biographicals.

Comment: I agree with you Chris. I try to logically group the commands as much as possible. I haven't gotten to the screen and command designs yet, when I do I hope to add clarity and detail to this area.

Answer (score 0):

> The way I understand it, the tasks, generally speaking, should line up with Commands or Functions waiting on the Server.

Or sometimes *events*, but the basic idea is right.

> Surely the User will not go from [first name] => to [last name] => to [address] => to [email], etc. -- in a wizard like style, where each wizard screen maps to a Command.

No, we usually want a coarser grain than that.  Some tasks do only require a single property, but several properties is a common case.

> How are the screens laid out when it's just not practical to isolate a single task?

By grouping together cohesive units; consider the Amazon order workflow -- there are actually several different sets of data collected (the order itself, the selection of payment, specifying new methods of payment, specifying the delivery address, specifying the shipping priority....).

> all the while they User is off-line.

See [CQRS, not just for server systems](https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/1980-cqrs-not-just-for-server-systems); but in broad strokes - treat the data collected from the user as events (FormSubmitted) rather than commands.  The offline device is the authority for tracking what the user did while off line; but the unavailable server is still the authority for the consequences of those events.  So the server is responsible for the merge when the client reconnects.

The precise details might vary from one domain to another -- for instance, in a warehousing system, where the offline device has been collecting information about inventory, you might handle the inconsistencies that the server observes during the merge by raising exception reports (the device registered this package leaving the warehouse, but we have no record of it entering the warehouse).